How do malicious users steal github pages custom domain bindings?
I have my own personal website on github pages, at metalelf0.github.io. It is also bound to a custom domain registered on namecheap at andreaschiavini.com.
The first time I set it up, I validated my custom domain via the custom TEXT record verification. I added it to my DNS configuration on namecheap, waited for the change to propagate, and finally performed the validation successfully.
Some days ago I found my website had been replaced by a malicious user. Visiting the custom domain returned a scam website. I went to my github pages repository settings and the custom domains settings were not there anymore, and trying to add them back returned this error:

The custom domain andreaschiavini.com is already taken. If you are the owner of this domain, check out https://docs.github.com/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/verifying-your-custom-domain-for-github-pages for information about how to verify and release this domain.

I checked my DNS settings again and I realized that after performing the validation I accidentally removed the TEXT record. Could this be enough for a malicious user to re-validate the domain and add it to another github pages repository?
I thought that to do so they would need access to both the DNS settings of the actual custom domain and the github repository, so without accessing my namecheap account to add the TEXT record they shouldn't be able to complete the attack.
I was able to solve the issue by re-validating the domain from my github profile settings rather than from my repository settings, but I'm still trying to figure out what happened.
Thanks for any help.
